# Fill an existing BST from sorted array of same size using inorder traversal

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, binary-search-tree

If I have BST tree of `int` of size `n` and a sorted array of `int` of size `n` (of different values) and I want to fill the tree with the array elements - I should do it by inorder traversal on the tree so that `arr[0]` would be in the left-most node and `arr[n-1]` would be in the right-most node. (So it takes `O(n)` time)

I tried to write a naive recursive function that do it but it doesn't work. It seems there should be done something to save the current index in the array.

```
void insert(Node* v, int* arr) {
    if (!v) {
        return;
    }

    insert(v->left, arr);
    v->key = a[0];
    insert(v->right, arr + 1);
}
```

How should I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decision is almost true. Just change function declaration to:

```
void insert(Node* v, int* &arr)
```

and when you visit the right subtree you should pass the next element of array the next way:

```
insert(v->right, ++arr);
```

`arr` is necessary to pass as reference `&`. It is related to the passing of the copy of pointer to array in your case. When return from child node to parent node, the pointer is reset to the first element of initial array `arr`. 
You can get the similar behaviour using pointer to pointer to array with minor changes in the code also.